# How to calculate the sum of column using Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet that has data, I need to get the sum, average of a certain column using Google App Script, someone to assist?

Comment: Use formulas to calculate  sum and average.

Comment: Also, please take a look at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/ and pay close attention to the range class and how to get/set values. The rest is simple javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function mySum(A1NotationString){
  var sum=0;
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(A1NotationString).getValues().forEach(function(item){sum+=Number(item);});
  return sum;
}


function myAvg(A1NotationString){
  var sum=0;
  var n=0;
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(A1NotationString).getValues().forEach(function(item,i){sum+=Number(item);if(Number(item)>0){n=i+1;}});
  return sum/n;
}
```